# Timestamp Date format no 'T'

Tags: ios, timestamp, nsdateformatter

Why can't I get the **'T'** to appear in my timestamp format?

I use:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

It is driving me crazy. I only get:

```
2014-05-08 15:00:50 +0000
```

I expected the following, with the `T`:

```
2014-05-08T22:31:51.900+0800
```

Comment: Show the code that creates and logs the date string you are trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just did a `NSLog` of the `NSDate` object rather than the `NSString` you got from calling the date formatter's `stringFromDate`.

If you do the following, you'll see the string using the formatter:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; // not needed, as it defaults to current time zone
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];

NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

---

By the way, to make sure this behaves predictably, regardless of the device's regionalization settings, you may want to set the locale, too:

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

For information on why the locale setting is advised, see [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: This is why I wanted the OP to post more of their code.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed; it would have been better if the OP included the code that generated the incorrect output. But it's easy to infer what happened here...